# Html2Canvas save png image to server by php showing half image and also file size reduced

Tags: php, reactjs

In my react js web application, I convert html div to .png image through html2canvas and then save to server file path through php.

After saving the file in server the image size is reduced and also image is showing half and rest of the screen is black.

I have tried with html2canvas to convert html div content to png image , its working in client side but when i save to this file in linux server then file size is reduced and not showing full image.

```
const input = document.getElementById('chart_application');
html2canvas(input, {
    logging: true, letterRendering: 1, allowTaint: false, useCORS: true, dpi: 200})
  .then((canvas) => {    
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const imgageData = imgData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    canvas.setAttribute('width',900);
    canvas.setAttribute('height',700);

    /*var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = 'yourImage.png';
    link.href = imgData;
    link.click();*/

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("data", imgageData);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'post', 'http://3.89.110.194/pdf.php', true );
    xhr.send(data);
    window.location.reload();
  });


$image = $_POST['data'];
$filedir = 'merp2/public/pdf';
$name = 'chart';
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$decoded = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', 
$image));
$path = 'merp2/public/pdf/'.$name.'.png';
unlink($path);
file_put_contents($filedir . "/" . $name . ".png", $decoded, LOCK_EX);
chmod($filedir . "/" . $name . ".png", 0755);
```

Comment: `$_POST['chartid']` - you’re not sending any parameter by that name, you send `data` only.

Comment: What happens when you use the generated data URI on the client side, assign it as src of an image element - does that show the full image then, or is it messed up there already?

Comment: the generated data URI working fine in the client side, but its messed up only in the server end.

Comment: What’s the purpose of `$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);`? If you send proper base64 encoded data to begin with, that should not be necessary.

Comment: if i remove $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image); still its not working.

Comment: also the image file size in server is less than the original image from client side.

Comment: Then check the length of `imgageData` on the client side, and `$_POST['data']` on the receiving end - those should match; if they don’t, then this gets cut off in transfer somehow.

Comment: As i have said image size is reduced to half when i save to server